# Adding squares in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have to write an assembly program to do the following,
sum = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + … + N^2, where N is a nonnegative word variable.  I am a beginner but I am trying to learn this. How do I stop the code at n^2? Am I on the right track with what I currently have?

```
.code
.main proc

    xor ecx, ecx    ;mov ecx to zero
    xor eax, eax    ;mov eax to zero
    mov ebx, 2          ;initialize ebx val to 2

Again:
    inc eax         ;increase eax by 1
    jz ready            ;if its 1^2, we are ready
    mul eax, ebx    ; multiply eax by ebx
    add ecx, eax    ;my total is stored in ecx and we add the next eax val 
    jl again            ;do it again

    ret
main endp
end main
```

Comment: First it would be helpful to know what assembler you are using for the x86 code. That said and same comment about the value for `ready` not appearing in your code.  The count-register is traditionally `ecx` so incrementing that is a bit more intuitive. You don't need `2` at all, you want to square the current count register -- but you need to preserve it to increment again, so `mov ebx, ecx` and then `imul ebx, ebx`. `ebx` will contain the square. If your sum is in `eax` now `add eax, ebx`. Now compare with your `N` value and `jge done` and define the `done:` label below the loop.

Comment: A multiply instruction multiplies, not exponentiates.  `x^2` is `x*x`.  As David says, to avoid destroying the counter, copy it and square it with `imul reg,reg`.  (That avoids overwriting EDX, so prefer `imul reg,reg` which works simply the way you'd expect, vs. `mul reg` which implicitly uses EAX and EDX.  `imul` with 2 registers is also faster.)

Comment: Note if this was to come up in real life, there's a [closed-form expression for the sum of consecutive squares](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Squares), that would do this in O(1) time (with just two multiplies) instead of O(N).

Comment: You have moved on to a new question. What do you find about the answer I wrote on this question here? If it solved the problem, then perhaps you could click the accept-arrow on the left. (I am the upvote on your question)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I stop the code at n^2? Am I on the right track with what I currently have?

Not really:

- `mul eax, ebx` (normally written as `mul ebx`) just multiplies by 2, but does not square as is requested
- `jl again` will continue the loop only if the total in ECX got negative, which is not going to happen first time
- `jz ready` claims to stop at 1^2, but why would you want to stop *that early*?

> N is a nonnegative word variable.

What does it mean for N to be a 'nonnegative word' ? It means that N is a value in the range [0,32767]. **Your code needs to work correctly for any value in this range**.

For big numbers (and not even *that* big), the result of `sum = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + … + N^2` will rapidly overflow the capacity of a 32-bit integer. Your code must abort the calculation if this happens. I would advice to start at N^2 and work your way down to 1^2 so that a possible overflow gets detected much sooner.

```
  xor   eax, eax   ; Result
  mov   ecx, N     ; [0,32767]
  jecxz Done
Again:
  mov   ebx, ecx
  imul  ebx, ebx   ; Max 32767 * 32767 can't overflow
  add   eax, ebx   ; This can overflow
  jo    Abort
  dec   ecx
  jnz   Again
Done:
  ret              ; EAX=[0,2147483647]
Abort:
  mov   eax, -1
  ret
```

Comment: Pretty sure the "nonnegative word" isn't telling you that overflow detection is expected, rather that you can assume things like `while(n--){}` will run the correct number of iterations if you want.  But that you can't assume it's non-zero, so `do{}while(--n)` wouldn't be safe: that could run 2^16 or 2^32 iterations if you don't bail out on `n==0` to start with.  But you can `dec ecx / jg Again`, because it's safe to run the loop with n=0, and also safe to skip that iteration if you start with n>=1.  Also, I wouldn't recommend using EBX; in most calling conventions it's call-preserved.